# Confluence PlantUML Macro - diagram creates boxs but not the associated text

Tags: confluence, plantuml

I've taken over a Confluence server (v7.13.2) with Confluence PlantUML Macro plugin v6.26. The underlying server has Graphviz v2.30.1 installed.

When I create the testdot PlantUML macro the macro displays the initial text like usual but fails to draw the second section of text which shows underlying variables and versions for the plugin.

I tested the PlantUML plugin using the following 2 examples:

```
@startuml
testdot
@enduml
```

and

```
@startuml
Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response
Alice -> Bob: A second Request
Alice <-- Bob: A second Response
@enduml
```

What actually renders on the server

> Testdot Render: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5x8g.png
> Alice&Bob pt 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/goj0Q.png
> Alice&Bob pt 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axnmr.png

I created the same PlantUML Macro on an test server which generated a correct example.

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEDIf.png

Thanks

Comment: Seems like the environment variable for graph viz and/or the dot binary isn't visible (path)?

Comment: I was not able to determine the problem, but after trying a few things like restarting confluence service, reinstalling graphviz, and restarting the server itself, the problem was able to fix itself.